# Alphabetically Sort Dropdown values in php/html forms?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Please Tell me how to Alphabetically Sort view of Dropdown Values in html/php forms.

Here is the Code :

```
<select name="bank" id="bank" style='text-transform:uppercase'  required/>
                                                 <option></option>
                                                 <?php $bank_name=mysql_query("select * from bank_details")or die(mysql_error()); 
                                                 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($bank_name)){                                                
                                                 ?>
                                                 <?php
                                                $bankname = $row['bank_name'];
                                                $bankname = mb_strtoupper($bankname);
                                                ?>
                                                <?php
                                                $bankifsc = $row['bank_ifsc'];
                                                $bankifsc = mb_strtoupper($bankifsc);
                                                ?>

                                                 <option style='sort'> <?php echo $bankname ?> - <?php echo $bankifsc ?> </option>
                                                 <?php } ?>
                                               </select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can order by SQL, which will always be faster than sorting with PHP:

`select * from bank_details order by bank_name ASC`

This is A-Z ordering

`select * from bank_details order by bank_name DESC`

This is Z-A

You can also order by multiple columns if you'd like, just add each in a comma separated list just like your select column list:

`select * from bank_details order by bank_name, city_name DESC`

Note that this will order by city name descending (Z-A) and bank_name by the default (A-Z, or ascending).  So, you can do:

`select * from bank_details order by bank_name DESC, city_name DESC`

Also, since there's a default, you can just do:

`select * from bank_details order by bank_name`

Comment: Thank u very much, it's just a small code and i am finding for it from last day, but i am unable to. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, see my edit for a little more detail about using multiple fields and such.

Comment: Hello Sir, Thanks Again, Please also Check this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31226919/autofill-textbox-values-from-mysql-query-result-onchange-of-dropdown-in-php, 

and answer