# Autofill Textbox values from mysql query result onchange of dropdown in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Please tell me how to change field value from mysql while change in selection of Dropdown values.

Here is the Code :

```
    <tr>
    <td>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" style="font-size: 16px;" for="inputEmail"><b>Loan from Bank</b>
            </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select name="bank" width="100%" id="bank" style='text-transform:uppercase' required/>
                <option></option>
                <?php $bank_name=mysql_query( "select * from bank_details order by bank_name ASC")or die(mysql_error()); while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($bank_name)){ ?>
                <?php $bankname=$ row[ 'bank_name']; $bankname=m b_strtoupper($bankname); ?>
                <?php $bankifsc=$ row[ 'bank_ifsc']; $bankifsc=m b_strtoupper($bankifsc); ?>

                <option style='sort'>
                    <?php echo $bankname ?> -
                    <?php echo $bankifsc ?> </option>
                <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <td>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" style="font-size: 16px;" for="inputPassword"><b>Bank Address</b>
                </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" class="span8" name="bank_address" value="<?php       ?>" id="bank_address" placeholder="Bank's Address" readonly>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
</tr>
```

I want that when i Select value of Dropdown box "Bank" value in Field "bank_address" Changes from Mysql.

Comment: Did you try to right something?

Comment: You have to try, but anyway just to give you a tip: you have to set a watcher for the `select` tag, for more info https://api.jquery.com/change/